# Cannot connect to cluster with cqlsh using secure connect bundle

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

I am getting error when I try to datastax cassandra instance.

```
 bin/cqlsh -u admin -p PASSWORD -b BUNDLE_ZIP_PATH
```

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', \
  {'xxx:xxx:xxx': ValueError('No host_id to create the SniEndPoint',)} \
)
```

Have anyone seen this error? This is a to a cloud managed datastax instance on IBM Cloud and the connection used to work before.

Comment: Are you connecting an Astra database? The reason I'm asking is that Astra is not available on IBM cloud so I'm a little confused. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by the embedded Python driver that cqlsh uses to connect to clusters. It indicates that it couldn't get the host from the secure bundle.

The most likely cause is that the secure bundle you're using is corrupted so I'd suggest downloading it from the source again. Cheers!